# Background picture in tcolorbox and pgfdeclarelayer mismatch

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

Why do pgfdeclarelayer{background}  and frame style in tcolorbox give different effects on the same picture?  How can we make them give the same result?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb, latexsym, amscd, amsthm, amsmath}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{background}
 \usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
  \usepackage[textwidth=16.25cm,textheight=18.4cm]{geometry}  % 
 \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
 \usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
   \begin{document}

\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[scale=.320]{goldshade.png}}}

\begin{textblock}{20.5}(7, 2.5)
Nguyen Vu
\end{textblock}
\normalsize
\thispagestyle{empty}



\begin{textblock}{20.5}(3.8,3)
\scalebox{7.486}{MEDLEY}
\end{textblock}

\vfill

\begin{flushleft}
\scalebox{.0072}{Math Center}
\end{flushleft}

\newpage

 \lipsum[1-4]
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagebreak

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,size=minimal,sharp corners,
  spread,
  phantom=\thispagestyle{empty},
  text fill,            % only, if \vfill is to be used
  leftrule    = 20mm,   % outer margin
  rightrule   = 20mm,   % outer margin
  toprule     = 25mm,   % outer margin
  bottomrule  = 25mm,   % outer margin
  left        = 15mm,   % inner margin
  right       = 15mm,   % inner margin
  top         = 20mm,   % inner margin
  bottom      = 20mm,   % inner margin
  frame style = {fill plain image*={scale=3}{goldshade.png}},  % background image
  opacityback = 0.285,    % transparency
  colback     = cyan!22,
]
%

\textcopyright{} 2009 $-$ 2018 David Nguyen \\
All rights reserved.

    This work is not to be  distributed and/or modified without licensse.

This content has been tailored by the author over his years of training the best mathematical minds. Problems in the booklet provides a wide array of mathematics flavours, enhance problem solving and thinking ways for young learners.
\vfill

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First edition:  & May 2010 \\
Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2011 \\
Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2016
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Institute of Mathematics\\
Vietnam

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologize in advance if I am saying something stupid, but are you sure that the background package uses your pgf layers?

Comment: OK, the \pgfdeclarelayer{background} is redundant. So it should have something to do with options in background package.

Comment: OK, I have added [opacity=1] option to the background package and it works. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @Thumbolt, if you found a solution, you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

I just use the background package this way then my question is answered. `\usepackage[opacity=1]{background}`